# trocar background do ion button com variavel

Tags: angular, ionic, background

estou tentnado mudar o fundo de um botão do ionic mas não consigo da forma que desejo que seria importar a cor de um uma arquivo com cores, e usa-la pelo nome que representa o hexadecimal, mas sempre fica como invalido, se eu usa a palavra, por exemplo: "red" funciona, se uso apenas um hexadecimal funciona tambem, vou colocar aqui como esta o scss que estou tentando trocar a cor do botão e da folha de estilos tambem:

```
@import "src/theme/colors.scss";

.btntest{
  --background: $redtest;
}
```

```
$colorPrimaryDarkBlue: #171d57;    
$colorPrimaryBlue: #4e56ea;    
$colorPrimaryDarkOcean: #101040;  
$redtest: #ff0909
```